# Where can I get documentation for gear vr 360 player

Tags: oculus, gear-vr, 360-virtual-reality

Hi I am a student and I try to make a 360 video playback app for samsung gear vr. I found this player but I cannot find any proper documentation.

https://github.com/yenchenlin/gear-vr-360-player

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no documentation you may want to contact the owner of that project.

You may want to know Samsung's GearVRf, an Android framework for GearVR
https://github.com/gearvrf/GearVRf-Demos/tree/master/gvr-360video
supports 360 video

Comment: There are more developers ready to help you at https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/issues and other resources such as https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/wiki